# jenv.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: python, praw

I am getting the following error when trying to run my code in Python:

```
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/jenv/0.2.0-201404260/libexec/../completions/jenv.bash: No such file or directory
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import praw
import pdb
import re
import os

# Create the Reddit instance

UA = 'A Bot'
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=UA)

REDDIT_USERNAME = '-snip-'
REDDIT_PASS = '-snip-'

r.set_oauth_app_info(client_id='-snip-',
                     client_secret='-snip-',
                     redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:65010/authorize_callback'
                     )

# and login

r.login(REDDIT_USERNAME, REDDIT_PASS)

subreddit = r.get_subreddit('all')
comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=100)
flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(comments)
already_done = set()
for comment in comments:
    if comment.body == 'Hello' and comment.id not in already_done:
        comment.reply(' world!')
        already_done.add(comment.id)
```

Here is the full console log of what happened when trying to run the Python code:

```
Last login: Sun Jul 31 02:45:28 on ttys001
cd '/Users/User/Desktop/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/User/Desktop/PRAW_Script.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/jenv/0.2.0-201404260/libexec/../completions/jenv.bash: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ cd '/Users/User/Desktop/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/User/Desktop/PRAW_Script.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/decorators.py:77: DeprecationWarning: reddit intends to disable password-based authentication of API clients sometime in the near future. As a result this method will be removed in a future major version of PRAW.

For more information please see:

* Original reddit deprecation notice: https://www.reddit.com/comments/2ujhkr/

* Updated delayed deprecation notice: https://www.reddit.com/comments/37e2mv/

Pass ``disable_warning=True`` to ``login`` to disable this warning.
  warn(msg, DeprecationWarning)
Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: "this won't work, can you please resolve these errors?" What errors? I don't see any errors.

Comment: @DeepSpace, try running it yourself.

Comment: No. How about you posting the errors that you get?

Comment: @DeepSpace Why are you so rude? I don't even get any errors.

Comment: If you don't get any errors then what errors do you want us to resolve?

Comment: @DeepSpace It won't reply to a comment `Hello` on the subreddit, [`/r/haykam821`](http://reddit.com/r/haykam821), with `world!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for comment in comments:
```

to this:

```
for comment in flat_comments:
```

`comments` is a generator, and you've already consumed all the comments it generates by flattening. Trying to iterate over it after that won't yield any results.

(You probably meant to use the flattened version anyway.)

Comment: Now it says `ImportError: No module named praw.`

Comment: This change cannot possibly cause that error.

Comment: Then why is it being caused?

Comment: That error means you don't have the `praw` module installed in your Python environment. Perhaps you uninstalled it or are using a different virtualenv now, etc.

Comment: It's already installed.